# Ruby Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (Errno::ECONNRESET)

Tags: ruby, ssl, zendesk

The following code will always end with an `#<Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect>` error message.

It may fail after 5 seconds, or after 30 minutes.

```
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new('newproduct.zendesk.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Head.new('/')

while true
  res = http.start { http.request(req) }
end
```

It happens when running on both Mac and Linux and is causing my batch jobs to fail.

It seems very difficult to debug but are there any things I should be looking out for?

Answer (score 6):

ECONNRESET is a socket error indicating the other side of the connection (in this case Zendesk) terminated the connection abruptly. Probably a network error on their end, or somewhere in between you and Zendesk.

I've seen this same error every one in every few hundred calls while using the Zendesk gem for ruby.

What worked for me was to rescue these errors, store the parameters of unsuccessful API calls in an array (or file or Redis) and retry later.